# How to disable a window with EnableWindow(), and gray it out?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

In .NET, when you set the `Control.Enabled` property of a Form or a Control (such a a ListView) to false, it becomes grayed out, along with all its children:

[image]

I do not see this happen in Win32 (`EnableWindow`), at least not with ListViews.

How do I achieve this effect in Win32?

Comment: Win32 does disable interaction with the child controls but doesn't change their visual state. .NET/WinForms has explicit code to handle this when changed using .NET. You could try emulating this for Win32.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
BOOL EnableWindow(HWND hWnd,
    BOOL bEnable
);
```

where hWnd is the handle to the control and bEnable is either TRUE or FALSE, TRUE enables the window and FALSE disables it.

Works fine for listviews.

It is worth nothing that in order to see the changes to its visual state, you'll need to force the window to be redrawn, e.g. by calling `UpdateWindow`.

Comment: Yes I did, and it works fine for listviews.  How are you using EnableWindow?  Are you passing the correct listview handle to it?

Comment: Sorry, there were two problems that were confusing me, making me think it wasn't working: it wasn't recursive, and it required an `UpdateWindow` in order for me to see the result! Thanks for letting me know it's supposed to work, that made me go double-check haha. :)

Comment: @Gunner Can I disable a window but still be able to drag it around? Or can I just disable the mouse interaction/selection?